# Not able to build local blockchain as per documenation tutorial

Tags: tutorials, local

Getting the following error and not able to build my first local blockchain using the documentation tutorial:
3 warnings generated.

```
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libprotobuf-lited.a(io_win32.cc.o) has no symbols
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libprotobuf-lited.a(io_win32.cc.o) has no symbols
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libprotobufd.a(io_win32.cc.o) has no symbols
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libprotobufd.a(error_listener.cc.o) has no symbols
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libprotobufd.a(io_win32.cc.o) has no symbols
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libprotobufd.a(error_listener.cc.o) has no symbols
  fatal error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: can't write to output file (No space left on device)
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ar: internal ranlib command failed
  make[2]: *** [libprotocd.a] Error 1
  make[2]: *** Deleting file `libprotocd.a'
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/all] Error 2
  make: *** [all] Error 2
  thread 'main' panicked at '
  command did not execute successfully, got: exit status: 2

  build script failed, must exit now', /Users/manekkooner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cmake-0.1.48/src/lib.rs:975:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you're are really in a bind on disk space then you can set SKIP_WASM_BUILD=true . If you need a new disk the 7000mb/s SSDs work really well.

Answer (score 5):

```
(No space left on device)
```

It looks like you need a larger hard disk.